# Ideal data structure for finding point and object collision?

Tags: data-structures, tree, geometry

I'm solving this problem, and I don't know which data structure to use.

I have multiple objects (convex polygons and circles) on a 2D plane, and for a given point, I have to calculate the objects the point lies within (they can overlap).

I've been reading about K-D trees, but I don't know how to "bend" it for this kind of objects. I've been also reading about bounding volume hierarchy, but I don't know if it would be optimal.

So, what do you think would be the best data structure for this problem? Time performance is more important than memory usage).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For most part, the "efficiency" of space partitioning schemes like BVH, kd-tree, R-tree etc, comes from smart tree construction. As long as you can build your tree well, you will have fast performance. For you case, I would say kd-tree is fine - it's very common with lots of source code available. So are R-trees. I don't understand what you mean by "bend" it for your objects. For Kd-Tree, all you have to decide, is given an axis aligned plane - for 2D case it would be either x = c or y = c, if the circle (or poly) lies to one side, or straddles. Rather trivial problem.